# Error: Byte "239" is not a member of the (7-bit) ASCII character set

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to read a xml file in netbeans.I use this code :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf ; DocumentBuilder db; Document doc = null;
  File file = new File(xml_url);
  dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  doc = db.parse(file);
```

and then it gives this error : `Byte "239" is not a member of the (7-bit) ASCII character set.`

xml header is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
```

How can I fix this? 
Thanks.

Comment: What does the complete `<?xml ?>` header look like? I suspect it's claiming to be an ASCII XML file although it is not.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: It's not possible that the application is using the default encoding for the platform. This is using the standard Java XML parsing API, and the XML spec requires UTF-8 as default encoding.

Comment: the problem is in my xml file there is & characters and this is problem thanks everyone

Comment: No, that's impossible. `&` characters wouldn't cause the error in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your XML file is claiming to be ASCII in the XML header, but it's actually not, since it apparently contains non-ASCII bytes.

Fixes in order of preference:

1. You should go to whatever/whoever generated the XML file, and get it/them to generate a new correct XML file.
2. Byte 239 or 0xEF hex, is actually the first byte of the (redundant) [UTF-8 byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) (BOM) `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`. I strongly suspect some software incorrectly added it to the beginning of the XML file. Notepad does, for example.

   If so, remove the byte order mark, it's the first three bytes of the file, just before `<?xml`. If your editor doesn't show it (e.g. i think Notepad doesn't, and [Netbeans might also have problems](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=161015)), find another that will.

   Just opening and resaving the file with an editor that doesn't support UTF-8 BOMs might be enough.
3. Another way to fix it would be to replace `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>` with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. This will only work if my assumption about the BOM is correct.

Comment: I didnt understand , my content is not ASCII you said?

Comment: Yes, you can fix this by either (a) changing the header to match the actual encoding, (b) changing the actual encoding to match the header, or (c) using XML entities.

Comment: the problem is in my xml file there is & characters and this is problem thanks everyone

Comment: No, `&` characters wouldn't cause the error in the question. Do you mean you got past it?

Comment: @user2942715: Maybe you had a Byte Order Mark in the file which was lost when you edited the file and resaved it? It could be invisible in your editor, you know.

Comment: @user2942715: If you've removed `&` characters that were part of character entities like e.g. `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&#123;`, you've just corrupted your data.

Comment: @user2942715: Did you or anyone else at any time edit the file with Notepad and save it as UTF-8? Because that would explain the problem.

Comment: I ve replaced the & character with some charaters like #$aa$# and then I ve replace it in my netbeans and then I send it to oracle. It works

Comment: @user2942715: If you've edited it with Netbeans, then there must have been a Byte Order Mark that got lost by Netbeans, maybe because of https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=161015 That is the real reason the problem disappeared, and removing `&` characters does nothing except corrupt your data. Try putting them back and you'll see i'm right.

Comment: @user2942715: It's explained in my answer, with a link to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented under Christoffer's post, but the stackoverflow asks for 50 reputation which I don't have. I am using macOS Big Sur. The vi comes with doesn't recognize byte 239, while pico does.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30181551)